# Bind an object to asp mvc controller from ajax request using asp.net core and Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-binding

I am struggling to post json data to asp mvc controller method from ajax request but asp mvc model binder is not binding it because of some unknown reasons.

I have tried to follow multiple answers posted here on SO including below

[Post json object to ASP MVC doesn't work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22704033/post-json-object-to-asp-mvc-doesnt-work-properly)

but my jQuery ajax method always posts null values to asp mvc controller.

Basically, I am trying to load an partial view via ajax request.

Ajax Request

```
var myData =
 {
        "Id": 7,
        "Name": "Name 1"
 };

  var obj = { 'test': myData };
  var val = JSON.stringify(obj);
  console.log(val);

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    url: '/Home/Partial',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: val,
    success: function (xhr, status, response) {
             console.log(response);
             $('#1').html(response.responseText);
         },
    error: function (err) {
        alert("error - " + err);
    }
   });
```

Controller Method

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Partial(Test test)
{
   return PartialView("_Test", test);
}
```

Model

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
}
```

Comment: Use `data: myData`. You're adding another object property in the values you're sending which is confusing the ModelBinder

Comment: {"test":{"Id":7,"Name":"Name 1"}} this is how my payload looks like after JSON.stringify() so i dont think there is any problem.. btw data:myData didnt work

Comment: The issue is `test`. That's not needed. If `data: myData` didn't work step through the request in VS. If you don't even get that far, check the console to find out what the error is in JS

Comment: @Pratham you could also consider using `public IActionResult Partial([FromBody]Test test)` so the model binder knows to check the body for the model.

Comment: If you are using .net core, it is very picking about requiring the `[FromBody]`.

Comment: @Nkosi That resolved the issue.. thank you very much.. i appreciate...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`myData` would have been enough to bind the object.

```
var myData = { Id: 7, Name: "Name 1" };
var val = JSON.stringify(myData);
console.log(val);

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'html',
  url: '/Home/Partial',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data: val,
  success: function (xhr, status, response) {
    console.log(response);
    $('#1').html(response.responseText);
  },
  error: function (err) {
    alert("error - " + err);
  }
});
```

You should also consider `[FromBody]` attribute on the parameter so the model binder knows to check the body for the model.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Partial([FromBody]Test test)  {
    return PartialView("_Test", test);
}
```

Comment: curious to know what will be the approach if i want to bind List<Test> on controller side ???

Comment: @Pratham You post an array of the objects and the binder will convert and bind it to the list

Comment: great..it worked.. model binder to the rescue.. is it possible to have List<Test> as a member of another class say Tests and then bind Tests in action method?    `public class Tests
    {
        public Tests()
        {
            tests = new List<Test>();
        }
        public List<Test> tests;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

May be a trivial issue but I overlooked it and had spent a few hours trying to debug this issue.

Make sure your model that you're binding has its properties labelled as **public**.